# iOS14-beta2 WKWebView crash on -[_UIFocusContainerGuideMapEntry setFocusContainmentFrame:] (in UIKitCore)

Tags: crash, wkwebview, beta, ios14

Recently we received lots of WKWebView crash logs on the iOS14 beta2 system.

Here is the crash log:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0xf7fff8018

Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0xf7fff8018.


libobjc.A.dylib 
__NO_DSYM_FILE__
2   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusContainerGuideMapEntry setFocusContainmentFrame:] (in UIKitCore) + 16
3   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusRegionMapEntry _mapEntriesByOccludingWithFrame:] (in UIKitCore) + 344
4   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusRegionMapSnapshot .cxx_destruct] (in UIKitCore) + 96
5   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusableRegionMapEntry description] (in UIKitCore) + 116
6   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusableRegionMapEntry description] (in UIKitCore) + 228
7   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusRegionMapSnapshot visualRepresentationWithMinimumArea:] (in UIKitCore) + 1844
8   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusRegionMapSnapshot visualRepresentationWithMinimumArea:] (in UIKitCore) + 672
9   
UIKitCore   
-[_UIFocusRegionMapSnapshot _snapshotByFulfillingPromiseFocusRegionEntry:] (in UIKitCore) + 848
10  
UIKitCore   
-[_UIStateMachine(Legacy) setStaticTransitionFromState:withEvent:toState:] (in UIKitCore) + 128
11  
UIKitCore   
-[_UIEstimatedTouchRecord initWithLiveTouch:freezeTouch:contextID:] (in UIKitCore) + 4
12  
UIKitCore   
-[UIWebDocumentView(Interaction) deepestNodeAtViewportLocation:] (in UIKitCore) + 96
13  
WebKit  
-[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _updateBackgroundTask] (in WebKit) + 272
14  
WebKit  
bool IPC::MessageSender::send<Messages::WebPaymentCoordinator::DidAuthorizePayment>(Messages::WebPaymentCoordinator::DidAuthorizePayment const&, unsigned long long, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendOption>) (in WebKit) + 28
15  
WebKit  
-[WKContentView(WKInteractionPreview) _presentedViewControllerForPreviewItemController:] (in WebKit) + 1564
16  
UIKitCore   
-[UIBezierPath encodeWithCoder:] (in UIKitCore) + 140
17  
UIKitCore   
__21+[UIColor blackColor]_block_invoke (in UIKitCore) + 140
18  
UIKitCore   
-[UIDisplayP3Color initWithDisplayP3Red:green:blue:alpha:] (in UIKitCore) + 196
19  
UIKitCore   
-[UIDeviceRGBColor set] (in UIKitCore) + 48
20  
UIKitCore   
__83+[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:onlySystemInvocations:]_block_invoke (in UIKitCore) + 312
21  
UIKitCore   
+[_UIAppearance appearancesAtNode:withObject:] (in UIKitCore) + 992
22  
UIKitCore   
__processEventQueue (in UIKitCore) + 8700
23  
UIKitCore   
_UIDrawViewRectAfterCommit (in UIKitCore) + 708
24  
UIKitCore   
-[_UIStatusBarLockView animateUnlockWithCompletionBlock:] (in UIKitCore) + 704
25  
UIKitCore   
-[_UIStatusBarDualCellularSignalView setTopConstraint:] (in UIKitCore) + 0
26  
CoreFoundation  
-[__NSDictionary0 copy] (in CoreFoundation) + 0
27  
CoreFoundation  
__copy_helper_block_e8_32o40o48b56o64r (in CoreFoundation) + 16
28  
CoreFoundation  
__destroy_helper_block_e8_32o40o48b56r64r (in CoreFoundation) + 16
29  
CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopTimerSetNextFireDate (in CoreFoundation) + 1072
30  
CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopTimerCreate (in CoreFoundation) + 384
31  
GraphicsServices    
_GSSendEvent (in GraphicsServices) + 252
32  
UIKitCore   
-[_UISearchControllerATVSearchBarAnimator _updateLayoutForGridKeyboard:animated:] (in UIKitCore) + 4092
33  
UIKitCore   
-[_UISearchFormSheetPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] (in UIKitCore) + 20
```

Is anyone familiar with this? Thx in advance

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653680. looks like I'm not the only one who encountered this.